# Trouble integrating a where clause into an existing select statement for reporting purposes

Tags: sql, t-sql

So, I have two queries - one that currently creates a report, and another query I wrote to append more data to the report.

I'd like to merge the new query so the data shows in the same dataset when I call to it in ASP.

I'm having trouble placing the new where clause so that it gives me only what I want. The queries work on their own but I just can't seem to figure out how to get them together without giving me a ton of extra data I'm not looking for.

Here is the original query:

```
SELECT 
transactions.date,
transactions.Pcode,
transactions.L,
transactions.iL,  
transactions.q,
transactions.mTo
FROM
transactions, 
productlist
WHERE
transactions.Pcode=productlist.Pcode 
AND productlist.client=transactions.client 
AND (transactions.mTo='NotAccepted' OR transactions.mTo = 'TheStage') 
AND transactions.client=232 AND ( tophysical = 'Place1' OR fromphysical = 'Place1' ) 
AND transactions.Date>= '2012-10-01' 
AND transactions.Date <= '2012-10-31 11:59:59 PM ' 
ORDER BY
mTo,
transactions.date,
transactions.pCode
```

The query I want to integrate is:

```
SELECT 
transactions.date,
transactions.pcode,
transactions.L,
transactions.iL,  
transactions.qty,
transactions.mTo,
FROM
transactions, 
productlist,
productarchive,
Shipping
WHERE 
transactions.pcode=productlist.pcode 
AND productlist.client=transactions.client 
AND transactions.mFrom='NotAccepted'
AND ProductArchive.TrID=Transactions.ID
AND ProductArchive.StID = Shipping.ID
AND Shipping.SID LIKE 'BAG%'
AND transactions.Date>= '2012-10-01' 
AND transactions.Date <= '2012-10-31 11:59:59 PM '
```

Final Query I came up with that's giving me tens of thousands more records than I want.

```
SELECT 
transactions.date,
transactions.pCode,
transactions.L,
transactions.iL,  
transactions.q,
transactions.mTo
FROM
transactions, 
productlist, 
shipping,
ProductArchive
WHERE 
transactions.pCode=productlist.pCode 
AND productlist.client=transactions.client 
AND (transactions.mTo='NotAccepted' OR transactions.mTo = 'TheStage' OR transactions.mFrom='NotAccepted') 
AND transactions.client=232 
AND 
( tophysical = 'Place1' OR fromphysical = 'Place1' OR 
    ( ProductArchive.TransID=Transactions.ID
        AND ProductArchive.StID = Shipping.ID
        AND Shipping.SID LIKE 'BAG%') 
)
AND transactions.Date>= '2012-10-01' 
AND transactions.Date <= '2012-10-31 11:59:59 PM ' 
ORDER BY
transactions.mTo,
transactions.date,
transactions.pCode
```

Thanks for your time, energy and help! Deeply appreciated :)

Comment: If the columns are the same, why not just use a `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Just union the clauses together? Yeah, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
transactions.date,
transactions.Pcode,
transactions.L,
transactions.iL,  
transactions.q,
transactions.mTo
FROM
transactions, 
productlist
WHERE
transactions.Pcode=productlist.Pcode 
AND productlist.client=transactions.client 
AND (transactions.mTo='NotAccepted' OR transactions.mTo = 'TheStage') 
AND transactions.client=232 AND ( tophysical = 'Place1' OR fromphysical = 'Place1' ) 
AND transactions.Date>= '2012-10-01' 
AND transactions.Date < '2012-11-01' 
ORDER BY
mTo,
transactions.date,
transactions.pCode

union all

SELECT 
transactions.date,
transactions.pcode,
transactions.L,
transactions.iL,  
transactions.qty,
transactions.mTo,
FROM
transactions, 
productlist,
productarchive,
Shipping
WHERE 
transactions.pcode=productlist.pcode 
AND productlist.client=transactions.client 
AND transactions.mFrom='NotAccepted'
AND ProductArchive.TrID=Transactions.ID
AND ProductArchive.StID = Shipping.ID
AND Shipping.SID LIKE 'BAG%'
AND transactions.Date>= '2012-10-01' 
AND transactions.Date < '2012-11-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, it might be easier to just use `UNION ALL`,  I also updated to use ANSI JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT transactions.date,
    transactions.Pcode,
    transactions.L,
    transactions.iL,  
    transactions.q,
    transactions.mTo,
    'query 1' source
FROM transactions
INNER JOIN productlist
    ON transactions.Pcode=productlist.Pcode 
    AND productlist.client=transactions.client 
WHERE (transactions.mTo='NotAccepted' OR transactions.mTo = 'TheStage') 
    AND transactions.client=232 AND ( tophysical = 'Place1' OR fromphysical = 'Place1' ) 
    AND transactions.Date>= '2012-10-01' 
    AND transactions.Date <= '2012-10-31 11:59:59 PM ' 
UNION ALL
SELECT transactions.date,
    transactions.pcode,
    transactions.L,
    transactions.iL,  
    transactions.qty,
    transactions.mTo,
    'query 2' source
FROM transactions
INNER JOIN productlist
    ON transactions.pcode=productlist.pcode 
    AND productlist.client=transactions.client 
INNER JOIN productarchive
    ON ProductArchive.TrID=Transactions.ID
INNER JOIN Shipping
    ON ProductArchive.StID = Shipping.ID
WHERE transactions.mFrom='NotAccepted'
    AND Shipping.SID LIKE 'BAG%'
    AND transactions.Date>= '2012-10-01' 
    AND transactions.Date <= '2012-10-31 11:59:59 PM '
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I put the union in on my side and it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: @user1757399 at least for the time being use this - make sure you use `UNION ALL` then you will not strip duplicates unless that is what you want.  Then you can spend time trying to consolidate the queries into to one to replicate the data. :)